# Wangkanai Detection in static helper class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Is there a way to create a static helper using Wangkanai.Detection in .net core?

I have the following:

```
public static bool IsMobileDevice(IDetectionService detection)
    {
        try
        {
            return detection.Device.Type == DeviceType.Mobile;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }

        return false;
    }
```

I'm using Wangkanai.Detection 3.0.0 in a .net 5.0 class library.

Comment: Why not just make an injectable service to help you?

Comment: Not sure that would solve all my needs since I use this in the controllers and in other helpers